# Changing Google Maps marker icon to custom icon

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, muse

I have been developing a site using Adobe muse, I have chosen to implement a customised Google Map on the company's contact page. I have done so using some basic javascript, inserted into the Muse document by inserting 'HTML Element' within there I have my JS.

I should also mention I have the Google Maps API (with my relevant key) linked in the 'head' of the page, via the page's Metadata (accessed via Page > Page Properties > Metadata within Muse).

Following the guides supplied by Google, I have created a custom map and then applied some extra styling, using JS generated through [https://snazzymaps.com].

My problem arises in trying to replace the default marker icon, with my own marker created in illustrator (stored locally on my iMac), I've followed a load of different guides and tried multiple ways of implementing the custom icon, but have had no luck whatsoever - can someone please show me where I'm going wrong? It'd be much appreciated.

Here's how my JS looks within the Muse HTML Element >

```
<script> 
function initMap() {
var myLatLng = {lat: 51.454137, lng: -2.473673};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('u64615'),{
    zoom: 16,
    center: myLatLng,
    styles:
    [
{
    "featureType": "administrative",
    "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#444444"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "landscape",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#f2f2f2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#f10019"
        },
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        },
        {
            "color": "#f10019"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.attraction",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "geometry",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        },
        {
            "color": "#f10019"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "labels",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "labels.text",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.business",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        },
        {
            "weight": "0.01"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.government",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.medical",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.place_of_worship",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.school",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "saturation": -100
        },
        {
            "lightness": 45
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.highway",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "simplified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "road.arterial",
    "elementType": "labels.icon",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "transit",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "visibility": "off"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "featureType": "water",
    "elementType": "all",
    "stylers": [
        {
            "color": "#163742"
        },
        {
            "visibility": "on"
        }
    ]
}]


 });

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Precision Profiles Manufacturing'
});

var contentString = 
    '<div>'+
    '<div>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<h1 style = "font-size:20px;padding-bottom:10px;"><b>Precision Profiles Manuafcturing</b></h1>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<p>The regions leading supplier of aircraft and precision engineering solutions.<p>'+
    '</div>'+
    '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    maxWidth: 200,
    maxHeight: 400,
});

marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});    }   </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick look through the Google Maps API would get you to this [page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#simple_icons).

Delving deeper into the API, you can see that when you instantiate a new `google.maps.Marker` there will be an optional property named `icon:`. This is where you can specify a string path to the directory in which you store the image you'd like to use.

So in full, the code to instantiate a new marker class would be:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: "https://your_domain.com/your_directory/your_image.jpg",
    title: 'Precision Profiles Manufacturing'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If we want to apply width and height to custom icon,

Refer to the below code,

```
let icon = {
   url: './path/path/custom_icon.png',
   scaledSize: { width: 69, height: 41 }
}
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pos,
  map: map,
  title: 'sample title',
  icon: icon
});
marker.setMap(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the "var marker" object, there is an "icon" parameter. According to the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom), you want to make another variable with your icon stored in it, and then set the icon inside of the marker object you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to set an icon on a marker. You can set the icon during the initialization of the marker or after (with `marker.setIcon (yourUrl)`).

Witch give:

1. Initialization

   ```
   var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
   var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
     map: map,
     icon: image
    });
   }
   ```
2. After initialization

   ```
   var image = 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png';
   var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: {lat: -33.890, lng: 151.274},
     map: map,
    });
   }

   beachMarker.setIcon (image);
   ```

[Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Marker) is the complete doc and [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#simple_icons) the google maps api reference.

Comment: This works great, however only with the Google beach flag icon you've supplied, all the Google Icons work as normal, yet when I link to my own icon it doesn't.                                                                                                 `   var image = '/Images/Assets/pp-location-split.svg';
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: 'Precision Profiles Manufacturing'
    });`

Comment: I must be linking my custom icon image incorrectly, thats the only reason I can think that would cause the Google icons to appear but not my own!

Comment: Try to set a complete url when you initialize the icon. Do you see some errors in your console?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the default Google Maps markers, you can only hide them.

So Maybe you can :

1/ Hide the default markers :

```
const styles = {
  hide: [
    {
      featureType: "poi",
      stylers: [{ visibility: "off" }],
    },
  ],
};
map.setOptions({ styles: styles['hide'] });
```

2/ Then make a [nearby Place request](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests).

3/ And add your own [marker with your custom image](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers?hl=fr#simple_icons).